# Safe number range for my own IDs in dynamic layout?

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

I am developing an Activity with a fixed and a dynamic layout part. The dynamic part (and thus the number and type of created widgets) is based on database values this way:
For every database row, I will have a group of widgets. And the components of each group depend on the object type (determined from one of the columns) of that database row.

For saving / restoring instance state, all widgets need to have IDs. I would like to ensure that my own IDs will never conflict with IDs that from the generated R class.

For better handling within the app (finding which widget maps to which field in which data object), a numbering scheme like ID = row * 100 + fieldindex would be helpful. Fieldindex is not exactly a colum number. Every object type should have its own fieldindices.

As the ID values in generated R seem not to have consecutive numbers, I can not just predefine a pool of IDs in R and used these without the need of an additional mapping.
Second reason against a predefined pool: The big number of fieldindices would result in a large ID pool. Third, the size of the ID pool would limit the row count that can be displayed.

Is there a safe number range I can use for my own layout component's IDs ?
Looking at R.java in the gen/ folder, I have the impression that generated IDs are all greater than 0x7f000000. Is that guaranteed ?
And if yes, is the range from 0x00000000 up to 0x7f000000 free to use or is it reserved for android's internal purposes ?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Good question, please read the FAQ. We try to avoid "thank-yous" and signatures are not allowed.

Comment: +1 interesting question. It seems that Android internally uses [0x1f onwards](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html#addToDictionary), and projects/libs use 0x7f onwards.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to avoid the same id? Only thing that necessary is:
[`An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be unique within the part of the tree you are searching`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id). So, you can use your formula

> ID = row * 100 + fieldindex

I will work fine, even if it is not unique in project.

Comment: Ah, that's a very interesting information. But there is still one thing left that I am unsure of: I am not the only one who searches my layout.
As far as I understand the docs, Android will take care of saving/restoring all widget's states with a unique ID (unique within the whole layout).
And I am unsure if there are some hidden internal IDs for the components I defined without assigning them IDs (labels, spacers, etc.).
Does Android assign internal IDs to them ? If yes, I think I must ensure they don't conflict with my IDs.

Comment: the id of a view is initialized like this: `int mID = NO_ID;` NO_ID is -1, and it is kept like this. So if you create a component programmatically and don't assign it an id, it not have an id (and therefore its state, if any, will not be automatically restored)